# How make /etc/hosts writable for php and not for user

Tags: php, apache, permissions, chmod

I've been trying to set this, but I'm stacked. I don't know how to set /etc/hosts writable for php, but not for user.

If I set `chmod 060 /etc/hosts` and `chown www-data:www-data /etc/hosts`, then php is unable to write (I supposed that php's group is www-data). If I set `chmod 660 /etc/hosts` it's working for php but also for user.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**
I found out that my user was in www-data group, so that was why applying 460 on /etc/hosts didn't work

Comment: What does "for user" mean? Which user?

Comment: Does PHP really run with that uid/gid? Also keep the hosts file readable for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is a terrible idea -- the hosts file should never be writable by any user other than root.

Nevertheless, the correct permissions to set to accomplish this would be:

```
chown www-data:www-data /etc/hosts
chmod 644 /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Its more safer to do something like this , 
1) change group to www-data
2) add permission 664 so that group has full permissions.

Comment: @acpmasquerade: There is really nothing safe about that configuration to begin with, so I wouldn't sweat the details too much.

Comment: instead of changing the user, atleast changing a group adds one step between. I prefer it over the one posted above.